# mongoid and cancan: problems using .only() and can? helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, cancan

I have an index action that I want to show all Products in a table, and if the current user has manage ability for the product, provide a link to that product.

My Product documents can be pretty large, so I want to use .only() on the query to fetch only those fields that are relevant to the table.

When I use .only(), I haven't been able to get a can? helper to function properly. Leaving out .only() works perfectly. I've tried adding all of the attributes to .only() that I thought might have an effect on the can? helper to no avail.

```
#products_controller.rb
...
def index
  @products = Product.all #can? helper in view satisfied for proper products
  @products = Product.all.only(:name, :_id, :price)  # can? helper never satisfied
end
```

What attributes are required on the model instance to satisfy the can? :manage helper?

edit:
ability.rb

```
 ...
 can :manage, Product, :_id.in => user.products
```

products being an array of product IDs belonging to the user stored on the user document

Comment: How did you define the manage abilities?

Comment: @ZachKemp added relevent part of ability.rb...I'm pretty confident in this seeing as things work flawlessly when leaving out .only() from the query

Comment: Try to use pagination instead. No Human needs so much data at once.